# Creating a free tier VM in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've spent a while trying to create a f1-micro instance in GCP but I'm completely stuck. The documentation says the machine needs to be in one of the three regions - Oregon, Iowa or South Carolina, and that it has to be a f1-micro instance. I've tried changing the machine configuration, checked all three regions - I just am unable to find f1-micro. The smallest machine I have is e2-micro, which isn't free.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select First generation N1 series in order to be able to select f1-micro instance type.[image: Please refer this screenshot]

Comment: Still displays 4.88$ - shouldn't it display free or something?